# Can we pass EL value as a parameter in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

```
<script>
    function newsArc(${item}) {
        var item = ${item};
        alert(item);
    }
</script>
<a onclick="newsArc('${item}')" id="itemlinkUrl" value="${item}">${quick.name}</a>
```

Comment: I need to send the values from anchor tag to the JS function please help me in finding some solution

Comment: Look at my answer. You can do that

Comment: Open JSP page in browser. Rightclick and choose *View Source*. Stare at it for a while. Hopefully you'll at a given point in time realize that JSP (with taglibs and EL and all on em) is after all merely a HTML/CSS/JS code generator. With the changed mindset/perspective from that point on, it'll become easier to write JSP. Certainly if you are already well versed with plain HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That passing is fine.

Where as your javascript fucntion is wrong. Corrected now

```
<script>
function newsArc(item) {
    alert(item);
}
</script>
<a  onClick="newsArc('${item}')" id="itemlinkUrl"  value="${item}"> ${quick.name} </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this because parameter can't be jstl

```
function newsArc(item) {
    alert(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting item as undefined

Comment: put this below line in your function and let me know, do you get any value : **alert(document.getElementById("itemlinkUrl").value);**